# Log File getting locked by Batch

Tags: batch-file, logging, cmd, locking

I wrote a relativly big batch script (multiple calls, all together ~150 lines) and have noticed an issue with a log file being created by said script. I'm only using the log file with the echo command like `echo this is a test >>test.log`, there are no other procceses writing or reading the file. Most of the time it works perfectly fine but just about one out of 20 times the script fails because the log file is locked. What could possibly cause this?

EDIT:
I went through old logs I had and i think I can safely say that the error always occurs after this command `fciv.exe !currentPath! -r -wp -xml %~dp0sourcehash.xml >>%~dp0Server.log` 
So this might actually be a problem with fciv.exe...

Comment: Are there multiple batch files that may be inputting at the same time? Th file will be locked if a process to read/write to the file is already open when a new one is started.

Comment: Impossible to say without more information.

Comment: @Arescet there are multiple batch files, but they arent run at the same time, they are all called by the main batch file which is waiting for their completion before continuing.

Comment: Are you able to single out the issue and include that code?

Comment: @Marcs I know it looks stupid without more context but I dont know how to specify :( The script is being run every hour an runs perfectly fine, then randomly the first echo command on the next start doesnt work. I tried googling it ofc and was kinda hoping this was a known problem with a fix....

Comment: You can try investigate the problem using [iotop](https://linux.die.net/man/1/iotop) in Linux, or are you running this on windows ?

Comment: @Arescet The only guess I have besides it being an issue with the command it self is that somehow the batch doesnt close itself properly after running. I now included an 'EXIT' at the end of the script, could that change the way the command is handling the log file?

Comment: @Marcs thanks but unfortunatly I am using windows...

Comment: A file failing to close could leave a file stream open, locking the file. Edit the question with any useful information you find.

Comment: I think I will try to use a work around I found, I can force the locked file to get unlocked with handle.exe if I am running the batch as admin. Now I just need to find out how to get it to properly run as one on this terribly locked down work pc... Thanks for your help!

Comment: On windows you can try [process explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) for checking process I/O, but I don't know this software much, I used it just for basic stuff.

Comment: Are you sure the log file is really locked by an application? Is the log file stored on a network drive or a local drive? In case of a network drive, are you sure you have always access to the network drive or are there short network losses. Or is the storage media of log file a NAS. Do you delete the log file before redirecting new messages into the log file? Sysinternals [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) is even better than Process Explorer for finding reasons on file access denied.

Comment: @Mofi the log file is on a local drive and is created by my batch so there shouldn't be any problems caused by wrong rights...

Comment: If value of environment variable `currentPath` varies and could contain a space or one of these characters ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~``, it is highly recommended to make sure that the value is enclosed in double quotes. Use `"!currentPath!"` if the string value of this environment variable is not already enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: @Mofi thanks will definetly try although it shouldn't contain any special characters or spaces...